# Whats the best way to edit custom aspx files in modern SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, aspx

I`ve uploaded some custom aspx files to "Site pages" folder and they open fine.
But now I need to edit them and wandering what is the best way/tool to do that.
If I put those files in standard doc library folder there is an text editor option but those files doesnt open but getting downloaded, so they must be in "Site pages" but in this folder there is no option to edit those aspx files.
I tried connecting SP Designer but there are some authentication errors I cannot resolve.
Maybe there is a way to connect Sublime or any other code editor to it?
Thanks